# First column in dataframe print?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I print a dataframe, usually the first column displays as going from 0 to `len(f)` and is unnamed. What is the name of this column? Is it just the indices?

I just tried printing a dataframe in an unfamiliar codebase I am working through, and the first column is going from 0 onwards in increments of 15. Why is this not going in increments of 1?

Here's a snippet (the print is huge so I'm truncating the columns and rows) of the printed dataframe

```
                 start_time                
0   2016-01-03 07:00:00+00:00   
15  2016-01-03 07:30:00+00:00    
30  2016-01-03 07:45:00+00:00       
...
```

Comment: Please copy paste the printed output and add it to your answer. Select it then, and press ctrl+K to add it to a code block.

Comment: I assume you are reading from a csv. where the index was written. Try: df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=[0])

Comment: @JasonBaker I think this dataframe was formed in the program and not read. I'm having a hard time finding the source of it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the index - and may have been created by selecting those rows. You can use the `reset_index()` function to reset the index to have an increment of 1.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

You can find out more information about [reset_index() here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).